# Dynamic polygons value with leaflet and shiny

Tags: r

i would like to generate colored polygons, with dynamic values based on option choosen form combo box (specific supplier name).

I used leaflet package to print polygons based on 'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame' object class. And it works fine. I have problems with using 'reactive' shiny function - is change object class from 'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame' to 'data.frame' - creatling leflet map is impossible.

Here is part of my code:

```
ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  sidebarPanel(
    # supplier selection
    selectInput(inputId = "inpSuppl", label = "supplier:",
      choices = sort(x=names(table(db$SUPPLIER)), decreasing=FALSE),
      selected = sort(x=names(table(db$SUPPLIER)), decreasing=FALSE)[[1]]
    )
  ),
  mainPanel(leafletOutput("myMap"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  myData <- reactive({
    data <- data[data$SUPPLIER==input$inpSuppl, c("A_COLUMN")]
  })

  output$myMap <- renderLeaflet({
    m <- leaflet()
    m <-  addTiles(m)
    m <-  addPolygons(map = m, data = myData(), stroke = FALSE, fillColor = ~pal(mapval))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Any idea?

---

Thanks so much. I have another problem - with color palette. i would like to change number of clusters and then color polygons. When i start app everything is all right, but after i change down number of clusters in input field, number of cluster don't work proper (number of cluster don't shrink).

```
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  leafletOutput("myMap", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
  absolutePanel(top = 100, left = 10, width = "160px",
    # input - supplier
    selectInput(inputId = "inpSuppl", label = "supplier:",
      choices = sort(x=names(table(db$SUPPLIER)), decreasing=FALSE),
      selected = sort(x=names(table(db$SUPPLIER)), decreasing=FALSE)[[1]]
    ),
    # input - variable type
    selectInput(inputId = "inpVar", label = "variable:", choices = c("turnover" = "VAL_1", "basket" = "VAL_2")),
    # numeric input - number of clusters        
    numericInput(inputId="inpClust", label="number of clusters:", value=3, step=1)
  )
)

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # dynamic number of clusters
  clusters <- reactive({input$inpClust})

  # dynamic data set - adding specific variable from db object to sh2 object
  ld <- reactive({
    # add aditional data to sh2 object (SpatialPolygonsDataFrame class)
    # from db obejct (data.frame class)
    sh2$mapval <- db[db$SUPPLIER==input$inpSuppl, c(input$inpVar)]
    # create clusters
    k <- kmeans(sh2$mapval, clusters())
    # add clusters to sh2 object (SpatialPolygonsDataFrame class)
    sh2$cluster <- k$cluster
    return(sh2)
  })

  # create color pal
  colorpal <- reactive({colorNumeric(palette="YlOrRd", ld()$cluster)})

  # static map elements
  output$myMap <- renderLeaflet({
    m <- leaflet("myMap") # preapare leaflet object
    m <- addTiles(m)
    m <- addPolygons(m, data = sh0, color = "black", weight = 1, fillColor = "black") # country polygon
  })

  # dynamic map elements
  observe({
    pal <- colorpal()
    leafletProxy("myMap", data = ld()) %>%
      addPolygons(stroke = FALSE, fillColor = ~pal(cluster), fillOpacity=0.6, popup = ~paste(mapval)) # powiats polygons
  })

}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of your data?

Comment: I downloaded 'shp file from here: 'http://www.codgik.gov.pl/index.php/darmowe-dane/prg.html' PRG – jednostki administracyjne. I would like to 1) filter data based on choosen supplier, 2) dynamic add data to 'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame' objecet 3) print result on leaflet map.

Comment: I don't think your link pasted in

Comment: You can pass shape files directly to leaflet without converting to a 'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame'. If the shapefiles are in a names list from the choices you could then use  `data[input$inpSuppl]`, and nothing will be changed.

Comment: `myData <- reactive({
        data <- data[data$SUPPLIER==input$inpSuppl, c("A_COLUMN")]`
       `data
      })`

If you tell the reactive function to return instead of just assigning, it should fix your problem. Also, you're only returning one column. Do you need to return more?

Comment: OK, filtering data works perfect. :) Now i must deal with changing palette. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  sidebarPanel(
    # supplier selection
    selectInput(inputId = "inpSuppl", label = "supplier:",
      choices = sort(x=names(table(db$SUPPLIER)), decreasing=FALSE),
      selected = sort(x=names(table(db$SUPPLIER)), decreasing=FALSE)[[1]]
    )
  ),
  mainPanel(leafletOutput("myMap"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  myData <- reactive({
    data <- data[data$SUPPLIER==input$inpSuppl, c("A_COLUMN")]
    data
  })

  output$myMap <- renderLeaflet({
    m <- leaflet()
    m <-  addTiles(m)
    m <-  addPolygons(map = m, data = myData(), stroke = FALSE, fillColor = ~pal(mapval))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Per the comments above.